# How should you name the solid-solution compound ScY(SeO4)3?

Tags: nomenclature

How should you name the compound $\ce{ScY(SeO4)3}$? There are 2 cations, and I know that $\ce{SeO4}$ is a polyatomic ion with $-2$ charge. However, I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to a [*double salt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_salt), but because of the chemical similarities between scandium and yttrium, $\ce{ScY(SeO4)3}$ is a [*solid solution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution) in this case. And the answers is you just name the cations in alphabetical order, then the anions like any normal salt. Thus the name is *scandium yttrium selenate*.

If the ratio between cations had a large difference such as $\ce{Sc_{1.9}Y_{0.1}(SeO4)3}$ It might be called *yttrium-doped scandium selenate*, but could still correctly be called just *scandium yttrium selenate* too.